# How to use JOIN in 2 string?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 table:

Table1

```
Name       Address     Phone
Nirdosh    Kth         96749343
Hari       pokhara     98493434
```

Table2

```
Name       Address     Phone
Shrestha   Daldale     96749343
Hari       pokhara     98493434
```

I want to JOIN in Name field which are string in type like this:

```
select Table1.*,Table2.* 
from Table1 actual 
INNER JOIN Table2 more 
ON LIKE ('actual.Name') = LIKE('more.Name')
```

But I am getting error.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `LIKE ('actual.Name') = LIKE('more.Name')`? Is that an equality comparison?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You usage of the `like` operator is wrong. You can just use the `=` operator to compare strings:

```
SELECT     Table1.*,Table2.* 
FROM       Table1 actual 
INNER JOIN Table2 more ON actual.Name = more.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

if you think Table2 Name, ie more.name need not be exactly as actual.name, you could use the following

```
select actual.*, more.*
from Table1 actual 
inner join Table2 more on more.Name like concat('%', trim(actual.Name), '%')
```